# Find Min-cut in a graph?

Tags: algorithm, networking, data-structures, c++14, graph-algorithm

Min-Cut of a weighted graph is defined as the minimum sum of weights of edges that when removed from the graph divides the graph into two groups.

I am unable to understand Min-cut algorithm what little I know is  -
Pick a random edge, and merge its endpoints into a single super node.
Repeat until the graph has only two super nodes, which is output as our guess for
min-cut.
I do not understand how it will give min - cut and how to do it ?

Comment: Is this Stoer–Wagner algorithm? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoer%E2%80%93Wagner_algorithm.

Comment: Sorry, I did not pay attention to word 'random' in your description. It seems that Karger's algorithm is what you are talking about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karger%27s_algorithm, but it's not for weighted graphs I suppose.